# How would one go about finding out the type of System.out.print()

Tags: java, types, primitive-types

Let say I have set some variable as such :

```
   byte a = 2;
   short b = 1;
   int c = 30;
   long d = 5;
   char e = 'E'; 
   float f = 2.21f;
   double g = 34.12;
   boolean h  = false;
```

I want to find out the value of the following calculation :

`(short)(g + a) != g == true || h && ! ( d % b >0) && d * f == e`

So I would go with :

```
System.out.println((short)(g + a) != g == true || h && ! ( d % b >0) && d * f == e;
```

This would return *true*. I know it's most likely a boolean. Let's say I wanted to make sure and have a command to print **both** the result and the type how would I do it? I want it to be a solution that can be reproduced over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println()` is heavily overloaded. You may do the same with your own method.

```
static void printValueAndType(int i) {
    System.out.println("" + i + " int");
}

static void printValueAndType(boolean b) {
    System.out.println("" + b + " boolean");
}

static void printValueAndType(Object obj) {
    System.out.println("" + obj + ' ' + obj.getClass().getName());
}
```

There are 8 primitive types in all: boolean, byte, short, char, int, long, float and double (you mentioned the all in the code in the question already). You will probably want a method for each.

Let’s try it out, why not?

```
    printValueAndType((short)(g + a) != g == true || h && ! ( d % b >0) && d * f == e);
```

Output:

> true boolean